# IRequestHandler Interface not implemented

Tags: c#, .net-core, mediator

I wanted to implement a simple mediatr task to send a record to database. 
I go the idea from https://jonhilton.net/2016/06/06/simplify-your-controllers-with-the-command-pattern-and-mediatr/.

However, I got this error that I have not implemented the Handle interface, which i have implemented below. 
Peeking the Handler interface is saw `Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);`

Now, what is the use of the cancellation token, and how can I make this code work.

Further, when I try using th `_mediator.Send(blog)` I got this error *The type arguments for method 'IMediator.Send(IRequest, CancellationToken)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly*
[image: Imediatr error]

I hope its clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Handle` method signature is missing the `CancellationToken`.
You don't need to user it per se but pass it down to any lower calls like a DB call. Your signature needs it but you can use `CancellationToken.None` if you don't pass one.

It is essentially used to notify lower dependencies that they should stop doing stuff because this operation is cancelled.

Comment: I've tried doing something -> 
Controllers/BloggitController.cs(46,36): error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'IMediator.Send<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse>, CancellationToken)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: var record = _mediator.Send(blog);